# Git Pull Request lagging branch conceptual clarity(In general merge commits)

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

In git how is it that PR with lagging branch compared to master just show the files in feature branch even though feature did not have the latest pull

When I first read about merge it was either FF or Merge commit. Merge commit creates a non linear branch(correct me if wrong), Now if my feature branch is behind in commits as compared to master, how is it not creating merge commit but just files unique to my feature are coming.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to create a merge commit, your feature branch needs to be rebased. Most of the forges (gitlab, github, gitea, ...) have a feature to do that automatically from a pull request web page.

This is a feature of the forge though, not of plain git.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Richter. I was wondering why is it working, Now I understand that Azure Repos is rebasing from the website itself when I create the PR